# Open103R, Open107v development boards - how to program?

Tags: android, linux, embed

ebay and other chinese sites are offering these development boards but it is not clear how to program them.

Is there OS for these boards ? Linux ? Micro .NET ? Android ?

I have played with Ardiuno and it was fun. Arduino comes with IDE.
These boards are more powerful, have Cam and Ethernet. 
Seems like more fun things could be done.

Please note I am hobbyist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, one of the language you can use is C. These boards can not support OS like Android because of the low operating frequency and limited memory.

I faced the same situation, and I ended up buying [this Ltouch development board](http://www.biemmeitalia.net/bmstore1x/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=2&products_id=1) that have many interfaces and support Android. It works very good.

A good free book is [this](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/~geobrown/book.pdf) from Geoﬀrey Brown, Indiana University about the STM MCUs and how to program them.